# mysql count UNION results that don't overlap

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, union

Alright so I have the query

```
(SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

and I will run the same thing using `COUNT(*)` with no limit

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) ORDER BY ups DESC,downs ASC)
```

Essentially what I would like to do is get the count of total results(without the limit), and also get the limited list.

The problem I am having is that when I run the count query, I'm getting a bigger number than the results I get back. The reason for this I'm guessing is when I get the results back, it filters out all the overlapping rows, where as the count only counts each, as I manually have to add them.

Any ideas on how to clean up this whole process?

Also, please note that the number of select statements changes dynamically, but I was hoping there was a way to get a general count that accounts for duplicates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this for the Count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Id)
FROM (SELECT Id From jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) 
      UNION
      SELECT Id From jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?) 
      UNION
      SELECT Id From jokes WHERE flags < 5 AND (title LIKE ? OR joke LIKE ?)) t
```

This should give you the unique count, and also notice that I got rid of the order by because it's not worth calculating for a count query.

Comment: Getting this error
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Bassam's answer is correct, but UNION already gives you distinct results, so DISTINCT is not necessary and is hurting performance slightly.